# How to pass the get var to the backend?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I use Laravel with a Vue SPA. The Server is Ubuntu / Nginx. I'm not the expert on servers...

The application works well on test and stage server but not on the productive server.

On prod, the get var from the request doesn't arrive in the backend.

`www.example.com?searchString=SomeText`

Where i have to change the setting from the server to solve it? If someone tell me where, i can extend this question with the code.

Here the try_file line:

```
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
```

Comment: can you show the `try_files` line from the `location` block from the nginx config?

Comment: try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;

Comment: You are missing a `?` if you are trying to append a query string to `/index.php`. Try: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`

Comment: @RichardSmith it works. Please post an answer